# How does Python know which number type to use in order to Multiply arbitrary two numbers?

Tags: python, c, pycharm, python-2.x

In **C**, I have to set proper type, such as `int`, `float`, `long` for a simple arithmetic for multiplying two numbers. Otherwise, it will give me an incorrect answer.

But in **Python**, basically it can automatically give me the correct answer.

I have tried debug a simple `987*456` calculation to see the source code.

I set a break point at that line in PyCharm, but I cannot step into the source code, it just finished right away.

How can I see the source code? Is it possible? Or how does Python do that multiplication?

I mean, how does Python carry out the different of number type in the result of 
`98*76` or `987654321*123457789`, does Python detect some out of range error and try another number type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean, how does Python carry out the different of number type in the result of  98*76 or 987654321*123457789, does Python detect some out of range error and try another number type?

Pretty much. The source code for integer multiplication can be found in [intobject.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a4a3a8b3f37f/Objects/intobject.c#l499). It multiplies the integers as C longs, then casts the longs to doubles and multiplies those. If the results are close, the long multiplication didn't overflow. If the results are very different, it switches to Python longs, which use a bignum representation.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, how do you find the intobject.c contains the source code of multiplication.

Comment: @Aaron: I've just explored the source code for a while. Eventually, you find things and get a general sense of where certain things are. I still don't know where a lot of stuff is, though it'd probably help if I used grep.

Answer (score 0):

The type promotion for mixed arithmetic is:

```
integer -> long -> float
```

The narrower type is converted to the wider type, and the multiplication is carried out.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Some examples to see what happens:

```
987*456 = 450072
987*456L = 450072L
987*456.0 = 450072.0
```

I hope I understood your question.

Comment: I mean, how does Python carry out the different of number type in the result of 
`98*76` or `987654321*123457789`, does Python detect some out of range error and try another number type?

Answer (score 0):

Variables are nothing but reserved memory locations to store values. This means that when you create a variable you reserve some space in memory.

Based on the data type of a variable, the interpreter allocates memory and decides what can be stored in the reserved memory. Therefore, by assigning different data types to variables, you can store integers, decimals or characters in these variables.

Python variables do not have to be explicitly declared to reserve memory space. The declaration happens automatically when you assign a value to a variable. The equal sign (=) is used to assign values to variables.

The operand to the left of the = operator is the name of the variable and the operand to the right of the = operator is the value stored in the variable.

Comment: This isn't accurate for Python. In Python, variables are typeless, and they don't actually reserve the memory to hold values. Values are stored elsewhere, and variables just point to them.

Comment: Do, i = 10 an then type(i)

Comment: That's not the type of the variable; that's the type of the `10` object it's referring to. Try `i = 'aaaaaaaaaa'` after `i = 10`, and you'll see a new type, with a value that wouldn't have fit into the int's storage.

Comment: Thats the point. Python interpreter decides the type and amount of memory at assignment

Comment: Okay, different example. Try `a = [1]; b = a; a[0] = 2; print b[0]`. If `a = [1]` reserved memory for a list, and then `b = a` reserved memory for a list again, `a[0] = 2` wouldn't affect `b[0]`. It does, because `a` and `b` refer to the same list.